# java - understanding static {}

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I came across this code in which I did not understand what static {} means:

```
public class BookProvider extends ContentProvider
{

private static final String TAG = "BookProvider";

private static HashMap<String, String> sBooksProjectionMap;
static
{
sBooksProjectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData._ID,
BookTableMetaData._ID);

sBooksProjectionMap.put(BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME,

}
```

Comment: It is static initializer that equals to static constructors in some other languages (e.g. C#).

Answer (score 1):

It's a static initializer. It's executed when the class is loaded (or initialized).

For more details please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html